# X2Go - правильно сконфигурировать X-сервер под Windows

Tags: linux, windows, консоль

Потребовалось мне развернуть терминальный сервер для пользователей. Денег нет, поэтому СПО. Доступ с Windows на Linux. Из всего опенсорчного ПО самым вменяемым оказался проект X2Go:

http://x2go.org

Исходники клиента под Windows:

```
git clone git://code.x2go.org/x2goclient.git
git checkout fb35d188406ba3fb2567d701e0398503e9253c02
```

В X2Go работает решительно все, за одним маленьким исключением: при копировании текста с кириллическими символами в буфер обмена на удаленной Linux машине, и вставке на клиенской Windows, текст превращается в циферки:

```
\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0433\u0440\u0430\u043c\u043c\u0430
```

В обратную сторону, кстати, работает правильно.

Пытаясь побороть этот глюк, я сделал себе среду, требуемую для компиляции X2Go Client под Windows, и собрал этого клиента.

Создание среды: [Установка и настройка комплекта Qt 4.8.6, Qt Creator 4.0.2 и MinGw 4.8.2 под Windows](http://webhamster.ru/mytetrashare/index/mtb0/1467373927r5m8rqalnb)
Компиляция: http://www.prog.org.ru/topic_30365_0.html

Но оказалось, что X2Go-клиент - это по сути всего лишь GUI-конфигурялка для специализированной версии X-сервера, собранного под Win. Называется этот X-сервер **VcXsrv Windows X Server (Custom builds by X2Go & Arctica)**. Его исходники не входят в исходники клиента X2Go. Находятся они в отдельном репозитарии:

https://github.com/ArcticaProject/vcxsrv

И там какой-то ад и содомия. Для сборки требуется Python, в качестве компилятора надо использовать неизвестный мне Visual Studio. Вроде как должно собираться на Community Edition, но от этого не легче. Какие-то куски надо доставлять через pip. Нужно раздобыть утилиты Gnuwin32 gperf, gawk, gzip, flex, bison, sed, и даже nasm. В общем, я в одиночку такой квест не осилю.

---

А теперь к сути вопроса. Я решил проверить, нельзя ли что-нибудь наконфигурять в конфигах X-сервера, идущего вместе с X2Go Client. В дереве установленых файлов клиента обнаружился каталог:

```
.\VcXsrv\locale
```

В нем есть следующие файлы с интересным содержанием:

```
compose.dir
locale.alias
locale.dir
```

Так же есть каталоги:

```
ru_RU.UTF-8
microsoft-cp1251
```

С интересными файлами:

```
Compose
XI18N_OBJS
XLC_LOCALE
```

Ну и если покопаться, то еще куча всего другого. Содержимое этих файлов мне мало о чем говорят, эту предметную область я не знаю.

Но возможно, через эти файлы можно настроить правильную работу буфера обмена в направлении Linux (сервер) -> Windows (Клиент).

Я сделал копию всех файлов в установочной директории X2Go:

http://dropmefiles.com/JabZw

Кто-нибудь может сказать, как можно тут наконфигурять правильную кодировку на клиенте и как это сделать?

Comment: 1. посмотрите, что именно помещается в буфер обмена: `$ xclip -o | hexdump -C`. 2. вообще следует отослать разработчикам сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Показывает вот что на строке с кириллицей:  

$ xclip -o | hexdump -C  
00000000  d0 9f d1 80 d0 b8 d0 b2  d0 b5 d1 82 20 d0 bf d1  |............ ...|  
00000010  80 d0 be d0 b3 d1 80 d0  b0 d0 bc d0 bc d0 b0     |...............|  
0000001f Последняя активность наблюдалась в репозитарии год назад. Задачу оставил, но не думаю, что разработчики бросятся решать проблемы расскоговорящих пользователей.

Comment: И если скопировать в Windows такую же строку, перейти в терминал и посмотреть xclip, то в буфере будут те же байты. То есть, кривизна идет на строне Windows, на самом терминальном сервере проблем нет.